# What is right way to avoid repeat object save to realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Here is my operate order:

1: fetch data from the servers

2: update UI

3: save data to realm

So I have an issue: When I fetch the data again, if the results contain the same data like before, So I don't want to save it to realm again. How can I solve it?

Comment: you need to create primary key for RLMObject. and then use addupdate method instead of add

Comment: @matloob Hasnain, Thanks for answer my confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a primary key for your class like

```
class Foo: Object {
    dynamic var yourPrimaryKey = 0
    dynamic var otherProperty1 = ""
    // and so on

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "yourPrimaryKey"
    }
}
```

Then when you save data

```
let foo = Foo()
//set properties for foo
realm.add(foo, update: true)
```

The documentation says:

> parameter update: If `true`, the Realm will try to find an existing copy of the object (with the same primary key), and update it.
>   Otherwise, the object will be added.